# center a matrix

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

The words "center a" probably give flashbacks to any decent HTML developer. Luckily, we are not working with divs, we are working with matrices.

Given a matrix where w=h, and given a "length" to extend it by, make a new matrix and center the old one in it, populating blank squares with the length. For example:

```
m = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
l = 1

OUT = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[1, 4, 5, 6, 1],
[1, 7, 8, 9, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

```
m = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
l = 2

OUT = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I would do more examples but they are tough to type out :/

Notice that each dimension has length*2 added to it. And that the "empty" space (the new matrix) is populated with the length. Here are the parameters and rules:

**Params**

- vars / method can be named whatever you want
- 0 < m.length < 11
- -1 < m[x][y] < 11
- 0 < l < 11

**Rules**

- Input will be `f(int[][] m, int l)`
- Output will be `int[][]`
- Use the closest thing to a matrix if not available in your language
- Standard rules apply
- This is `code-golf`, so shortest code per language wins!

Good luck :)

Comment: Should "0 < l < 11" say "0 < length < 11"?

Comment: lowercase L shows up weird so yeah, I guess.

Comment: oh ok i will fix that

Comment: Are you sure the fill in your second example should be 1 and not 2?

Comment: Please, post your future challenges to [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active) first.

Comment: Isn't the second example incorrect if we should fill it with the length? EDIT: Ah, I see @Adám already mentioned this above.

Comment: the IO are a bit strict, is it allowed to output a matrix of floats? (with the same values)

Comment: @MarcMush I took that to mean that the input will be whole numbers, not that the actual data type would be integer. Indeed, some languages don't have integers, e.g. JavaScript.

Comment: Please address the fill value confusion as pointed above, and [relax I/O requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/36398)

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Port of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247244/43319).

Anonymous tacit infix function taking taking `l` as left argument and `m` as right argument.

```
∾˘⟜⌽⟜⍉⍟4⍟⊣
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+y5jin5zijL3in5zijYnijZ804o2f4oqjCgrin6gKMSBGIDPigL8z4qWKMSvihp)

…`⍟⊣` repeat `l` times:

…`⍣4` repeat 4 times:

…`⟜⍉` transpose, then:

…`⟜⌽` flip upside-down, then:

…`∾˘` concatenate `l` to each row of that

**Alternatively:**

`∾˘` concatenate `l` to each row of…

`⟜⌽` the flipped upside-down…

`⟜⍉` transpose

`⍟4` done four times

`⍟⊣` done `l` times

Comment: Just to complete the set: [J port](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/a6wcavQcdOKsTOKsov9rcvk56SmgiIFFTBSs1DV0K3QqNGv0NCq0K7RVKjWr9RT1KhQq1bm4UpMz8hWMFNIUMvWMFYwhXHV1CG0IFjZSMPoPAA "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Yeah. If this gets reopened, will you post that, or do you want me to?

Comment: Go for it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE) (non-competing<sup>*†*</sup>), 5 bytes

```
VQA.X
```

Since the integers are guaranteed to be single digits, I/O are multi-line strings (<sup>*†*</sup>since the challenge asks for a strict integer-matrix I/O, I've marked it as non-competing).
Takes the length as first input, and matrix-string as second.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/PyzQUS/i/38jLiVDI@OYPBNTs5g8cwtLJQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
V      # Loop the (implicit) first input amount of times:
       #  (use the implicit second multi-line input-string)
 Q     #  Push the first input again
  A    #  Deep apply the following command:
   .X  #   Surround the string with this character around it
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
##~ArrayPad~#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1m5zrGoKLEyIDGlTtlI7X9AUWZeib5DWrRrcka@voOyDoh2UDaKVXNwcKjmqq6uNtQx0jGu1ak20THVMQPS5joWOpa1tTqGtTr4pI1quWr/AwA)

Built-in. Input `[m, l]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 64 bytes

```python
lambda n,l:(c:=[[l]*(l+l+len(n))]*l)+[l*[l]+e+l*[l]for e in n]+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rYxNDoIwEEb3nKI7ZujEBPAHSThJ6aIgREgdmsrG09eCxhOYWbyXyZfnXut94bJyPoxNG6x5dDcjmGwNfd0oZXUGVsYbGBhRZxalsln8y0HuHBcvBjGxYC374PzEK6Qtp4d5mRjSL5@rB4Pb1mzbbtdu0xGUyqmgUpM60onOkReq6Ko15YiYJJ/mT/4VL2I8vAE)

It's been a while since I posted a working answer...so feel free to suggest golfs. There are probably plenty of them... ;)

Sure enough... thanks @Jitse for -2 bytes.

## Explanation

Constructs a matrix.

First `l` rows: `l` repeated `l+l+len(n)` times (length of n plus the extra, twice).

Next `len(n)` rows: `l` repeated `l` times, plus the current row of the matrix,  plus `l` repeated `l` times.

Final `l` rows: same as first `l` rows.

Then I use the walrus operator to save bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·FøXδ.ø
```

First input is the length, second the matrix.

-1 byte thanks to *@emanresuA*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Ha3wzsizm3RO7zjf@yh3f@NuKKjDXWMdIxjdaJNdEx1zIC0uY6FjmVsLAA). (Footer `]»` added to pretty-print the output, feel free to remove it to see the actual matrix result.)

**Explanation:**

```python
·         # Double the (implicit) input
 F        # Loop that many times:
   ø      #  Zip/transepose the matrix; swapping rows/columns
          #  (which will use the second implicit input in the first iteration)
     δ    #  Map over each row:
      .ø  #   Surround the row with a trailing/leading
    X     #   1 (as integer, a literal `1` would add strings `"1"`,
          #      so with this the output is cleaner)
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

If the filler character should be the input-length (as the challenge spec says, but the second test case contradicts), it would still be 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) by replacing the `X` with `¹` (first input): [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Ha3wzsO7Ty3Re/wjv@xh3b/N@KKjjbUMdIxjtWJNtEx1TED0uY6FjqWsbEA).

Comment: I think the fill should be the length, not 1. (I made this mistake too by reason of the question only providing one example)

Comment: @ophact The second example has `1`s padded as well, though.. :/

Comment: But the question says "make a new matrix and center the old one in it, populating blank squares with the length."

Comment: @ophact Yeah, I noticed. I'll wait for OP to update before I fix it, but should be the same byte-count anyway by replacing `X` with `¹`.

Comment: [7](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Ha3wzsizm3RO7zj/38jruhoQx0jHeNYnWgTHVMdMyBtrmOhYxkbCwA)?

Comment: @emanresuA Ah, of course. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 48 bytes

```r
f=function(m,l)"if"(l,f(t(rbind(1,m,1)),l-.5),m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYtBCoAgEADvPcPTLmyBRYcCf9EH0lgQdAUxqteb/aDTMDCTa2XDp7jik0CkgMqzgkAMBbL1coCmSBqRQj/MSBErQ9xL9jfodSHJ6TITiUuhwT6fbtiG7k82Yn0B)

-7 bytes thanks to pajonk.

+6 bytes if padding with `l` rather than `1`.

Comment: [-7 bytes](https://tio.run/##jYtBCoAgEADvPcPTLmyBRYcCf9EH0lgQdAUxqteb/aDTMDCTa2XDp7jik0CkgMqzgkAMBbL1coCmSBqRQj/MSBErQ9xL9jfodSHJ6TITiUuhwT6fbtiG7k82Yn0B "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk that is brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://dyalog.com), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

Anonymous infix lambda taking `l` as left argument and `m` as right argument.

```apl
{⍺⌽⍤⍉⍤,⍣4⍣⍺⊢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/v/pR765HPXsf9S551NsJJHUe9S42AWKQcNeiR71ba/@nPWqboPGot@9RV/Oj3jWPerccWm/8qG3io76pwUHOQDLEwzNY81HHDJAYkOyb6hXs7/ffUCFNQT062lDHSMc4VifaRMdUxwxIm@tY6FjGxqpzGeGXBwA) (Uses Extended because TIO's plain Dyalog is outdated)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍺` is left argument and `⍵` is right argument.

`⊢⍵` on the argument…

…`⍣⍺` repeat `l` times:

…`⍣4` repeat 4 times:

`⍺`…`⍤,` prepend `l`, then:

`⌽⍤⍉` mirror the transpose

Comment: @ovs Yes, of course. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, I was about to post that, but feel free to.

Comment: No do that if you want. I've written a comment because I felt it was too similar for its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
Nest[Thread@*Reverse@*Append[#],#2,4#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y@1uCQ6JKMoNTHFQSsotSy1qDjVQcuxoCA1LyVaOVZH2UjHRDlW7X9AUWZeib5DerSRTnW1oY6RjnGtTrWJjqmOGZA217HQsaytjf0PAA)

-15 bytes from ATT

---

Explanation:

`Nest[` Repeat the following process

`Thread@*Reverse@*` Transpose and reverse (rotate clockwise) our matrix

`Append[#],` with the padding variable appended.

`#2,` Start with our original matrix

`4#]&` and do this four times the padding amount times.

Longer version that doesn't rotate the matrix:

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 98 bytes

```
f[m_,l_]:=Nest[{v}~Join~Append[#,v=Array[l&,a+l]]&,PadLeft[PadRight[#,a=Tr[1^m]+l,l],a+l,l]&/@m,l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLCsIwEADQwwjddEBa/0LAbkWkiLthLINNbSCpJYaChPTqMa7e5hl2vTTs1JNj7NA0oBs6iqv8OPRTmM9vNczVOMqhxQVMorKWv6gz4FwTZVBze5Gdw@RNvXqXEou7xeJhKNeg6R8T2fJkErG2anDYofcFlLAK4NewgW1yB3s4hAAlUfwB)

Wouldn't be surprised if this gets golfed significantly further than its current state (I suspect it would involve either MovingMap or just Transposing the matrix to do the sides instead of PadLeft/Right), but it works.

---

Explanation:

`f[m_,l_]:=` Create a function (because of slot collisions)

`Nest[` that will repeatedly apply

`{v}~Join~` prepending v to our list

`Append[#,v=` and appending it, where v is

`Array[l&,a+l]]]&` a list of the padding amount, of a size equal to a plus the padding amount.

`PadLeft[` Our starting input will be padding the left of

`PadRight[#,a=` the right-padded version of the list, padded to length a,

`Tr[1^m]+l,` where a is the length of the matrix plus the padding amount,

`l],` using l as the element to pad with.

`a+l,` The left padding will be padded to length a+l,

`l]&` still using element l.

`/@m,` Do this padding to each row of our input matrix.

`l]` Finally, do the repeated application of the first step l times.

Comment: 39 bytes inputting [`[l][m]`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P@f9pIV@qcUl0dXKyjo5tWoODg5BqWWpRcWpDsrv@9vVdJR1THJi1f4HFGXmleg7pEcbxUZXVxvqGOkY1@pUm@iY6pgBaXMdCx3L2trY/wA) and [`[l,m]`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773y@1uCQ6JKMoNTHFQSsotSy1qDjVQcuxoCA1LyVaOVZH2UjHRDlW7X9AUWZeib5DerSRTnW1oY6RjnGtTrWJjqmOGZA217HQsaytjf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

*(-6 bytes if we always fill with 1's instead)*

Expects `(length)(matrix)`.

```javascript
(n,N=n)=>g=m=>n--?g([q=(m=m.map(r=>[N,...r,N]))[0].map(_=>N),...m,q]):m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYxLCsIwFAD3OcVbvsBLsPUvvHiDXCAEKbUtSpP0I14/Wl25dDkDM/fqWc31dBseKqZrk1vOGMlylGw6DmyiUucO3cgYOOhQDTixcZa01hNZL6Vb@Y@@sLFy0YFGL08h1ynOqW90nzpssZDoBIArCEqCtacFNgRbgt0X9gQHgqMX76n4jcu/4vwC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
d(∩ƛ¹p¹J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJkKOKIqcabwrlwwrlKIiwiOynigYsiLCIyXG5bWzEsMiwzXSxbNCw1LDZdLFs3LDgsOV1dIl0=) Port of [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247245/80050).

If it should be filled with `1`s instead (like in the test cases), then swap the tiny `¹` with a full-size `1` for the same byte count.

**How it works:**

```bash
d(∩ƛ¹p¹J
d(         # Repeat 2*(length) times:
  ∩        #   Transpose
   ƛ       #   For each row:
    ¹p     #     Prepend length
      ¹J   #     Append length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 75 bytes

```hs
f m l=let r=replicate;b=r l$r(length m)1;a=r l 1in map(\x->a++x++a)$b++m++b
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `combinators.extras`, 51 bytes

```
[ dup <array> '[ [ _ 1surround ] map flip ] twice ]
```

Requires modern Factor for `1surround`, so have a picture:

[image]

Here is a version that works on TIO for 3 more bytes:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc07C8IwGIXhvb/ibE4WvF9xFRcXcSpF0vQrBNM0fknQUvrbY@j28HLgNEL6juPzcbtfj3gTG9IQzKJ3aLiHo08gI8lBdm2ljEhrl9PPs3CwTN73lpXxOGXZgAELLLHCmLTGBttJO@xxSBqxjAXqYHGeHi6YFSjwmpILzF0wNUq0wqLRyib6r5KEMkqhNZxqraa5F5WmPP4B)

### Explanation

- `dup <array>` Create an array of \$l\$ \$l\$s.
- `[ ... ] twice` Call a quotation two times.
- `[ _ 1surround ] map` Append and prepend a copy of the array to each row of the matrix.
- `flip` Transpose.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 46 bytes

```julia
m>n=0<n ? [(a=ones(size(m,2));) m' a]>n-.5 : m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcqxDoIwFAXQna@4m@8larwIDgL1QwhDExlq2iexmqA/X1cnz3xurxg811KSs@HQGy4YxQ93m7Pk8JklbWvVTpE28JOz3b7FGalcQ16if8tIgjV47MAGbMHT5KjV8gj2jCZa/Z3Nzyxf)

- can take non-square matrices
- recursive function. At each half-step, adds a column of ones to each side of the matrix
- output is with floats, +1 byte to have ints [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcqxDoIwFAXQna@4m@8larwIDiL1QwhDExlq2hdCIVF/vq5Onvk8txg8X6UkZ/3pZrhjEN@vyzZlyeEzSdrXqp0i7eBHZ4djiytSeYQ8R/@WgQRr8NyBDdiCl9FRq3kJtkYTrf7O5meWLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｆ⁴«ＦηＦθ⊞κθ≔Ｅ§η⁰Ｅ⮌η§μλη»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYs9C8IwGITn5lfcmBdewY/6Rafi5CAU15Ih1GqKtbVJLYL422NacLk7nrsrjLZFq2vvr62FjAkfEU3RECbvCNnLGXlndJSIKHWuujXypJ8y7Y/NpXxLw5gTY0TnciitK8Ob8a8fjJooABP@X5HZqunlQbs@rCjxPl8wcjHqkrFSLPKYsWZsxrhl7Bh7pZSfDfUP) Link is to verbose version of code. Does not require the matrix to be square. Takes `l` as the first argument for consistency (see below). Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Repeat four times.

```
ＦηＦθ⊞κθ
```

Append `l` to each row `l` times. (`ＦθＦη⊞λθ` also works of course.)

```
≔Ｅ§η⁰Ｅ⮌η§μλη
```

Rotate the matrix.

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the matrix in Charcoal's default format (each element on its own line and rows double-spaced).

String-based version inspired by @KevinCruijssen's Pyke answer for 19 bytes:

```
ＮηＷＳ⊞υιＵＯ⁺⊗ηＬυθＭηηυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxJDgIhEEX3nIJlkeCinU0vdWPiQOIJoCUNSQk2Q3t8LN39vLz/BqfTEDW2dg7vWm71ZWyCSfTs4zxaDn/8KMmHEYTgqmYHVXJPxt1gJKqwZjjFatA@6Sn5xYaxkCVoH3UuBMm@xtnCJPmvrShXSOhb61i3XLH1Zst2@wNrixm/) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `l` as the first argument. Explanation:

```
Ｎη
```

Input `l` as an integer (`θ` still contains `l` as a character).

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the matrix.

```
ＵＯ⁺⊗ηＬυθ
```

Draw an expanded matrix filled with the character `l`.

```
Ｍηηυ
```

Output the input matrix in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 66 bytes

```perl
sub f{my$f=[1,(1)x@_];($l=pop)?f($f,(map[1,@$_,1],@_),$f,$l-1):@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLbaoNAEIav61MMi2V3YRIwTXpIsNn7QnPTOxVpGy1po24TAwnis9tZDwiptNAu4izfPwd@HR3ttrOq2h9eIC6Skx27noPCkUcVBgthb12dabmMhR2jSJ41icoO0QlQhRIJ2tuRI@cqLKs42wkL6Hj1GzzKhQnCVYANAG@KMEO47sENwi3CXdARpwnufZdALfqnr2uAaX6O2xHnuB000KTrXdNW/IeDyY8Ohn38JrY@B8Te7YDYe/7DzG9fxpJFfUlOwk7ot6PKDrl0aRsWLVdvWe7GQtWy7CjYlOeuEy3qgh6b7BrTpcV6t0nzGNiIDlzuwUQ/jY46es2j9dxPTS8/pQJzp@CnfsrQuqBaI0H0WfeFJfDsg8Mc@OPqCVYPfGGVltlxGlgwj43fs00qGJpq2uqCe7xBHLlZcDnmAS9pxccsYGX1BQ)